# htaccess rewriterule to send a file to another file in the same directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a directory that contains an index.php and an index.html file, both being published from a CMS. There's a specific IP address that will attempt to access index.html, but should instead be shown index.php in the same directory. All other traffic should act as normal.

I've been working with some variations of this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^123\.456\.789\.10
RewriteRule ^index\.(htm|html?)$ index.php [NC,R=301,L]
```

This does do the redirect, but of course it goes to the root of the site rather than staying in the same directory. It's somewhat unclear what the directory path will be in all cases, so I'd like to tell Apache to stay in the same directory it's in.

Is this possible?

Thanks,
Jonathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have this rule for IP: `123.456.789.10` then you shouldn't have this IP with 
negation like: `RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !`

Try this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdir/

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} ^123\.456\.789\.10$
RewriteRule ^index\.html?$ index.php [NC,R=302,L]
```

Comment: Sorry about the accidental negation there. I was trying the reverse and didn't delete it. Edited. However, this code still tries to send me to index.php on the root of the server.

Comment: Where did you place it .htaccess in DOCUMENT_ROOT or in a sub dir?

Comment: In that case use `RewriteBase /subdir/` line just below `RewriteEngine On` line.